# Canonical form of a PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I need to classify and find the canonical form of the PDE \begin{align}\label{pde1}
   u_{xx}-(\mathrm{sech}^4\,x)u_{yy}=0 \end{align}

This is what i've tried : Comparing with the general form of a second order linear PDE
\begin{align}\label{pdel}
    a(x,y)u_{xx}+2b(x,y)u_{xy}+&c(x,y)u_{yy}+d(x,y)u_x +e(x,y)u_y+f(x,y)u+g(x,y)=0 \nonumber 
\end{align}
We have $a=1, c=-\mathrm{sech}^4\,x$ and $b=0$, which gives us $b^2-ac=\mathrm{sech}^4\,x$. So the PDE is hyperbolic, parabolic or elliptic depending upon $\mathrm{sech}^4\,x>0$, $\mathrm{sech}^4\,x=0$ or $\mathrm{sech}^4\,x<0$. For the last two cases it seems that there's no solution, so we conclude that the PDE is hyperbolic in nature. Now we transform the PDE to it's canonical form. Firstly, we solve the following ODE to find the new coordinate system ($\xi,\eta$) for the PDE
\begin{align}\label{ode1.1}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}&=\frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}=\pm \mathrm{sech}^2\,x 
\end{align}
Solving above ODEs we get $y-\tanh\,x=\text{constant}$ and $y+\tanh \, x=\text{constant}$. We choose $\xi:=\varphi(x,y)=y-\tanh\,x$, and $\eta:=\psi(x,y)=y+\tanh\,x$.
On differentiating the equation \begin{align}\label{u1.1}
    u(x,y)=w(\varphi(x,y),\psi(x,y))=w \left(y-\tanh\,x,y+\tanh\,x \right)
\end{align}
with respect to $x$ and $y$ we obtain
\begin{align}\label{ux1.1}
    u_x=-\mathrm{sech}^2(x)w_{\xi}+\mathrm{sech}^2(x)w_{\eta}, ~~u_y=w_{\xi} +w_{\eta}
\end{align}
and taking another derivative yields
\begin{align}\label{uxx1.1}
    u_{xx}&=\mathrm{sech}^4(x)\left( w_{\xi\xi}-2w_{\xi\eta}+w_{\eta\eta}\right)+2\tanh(x)\mathrm{sech}^2(x)(w_{\xi}-w_{\eta}) \nonumber \\u_{yy}&=w_{\xi\xi}+2w_{\xi\eta}+w_{\eta\eta}  
\end{align}
And we solve $(x,y)$ in terms of $(\xi,\eta)$ to get
\begin{align}\label{xieta}
    x=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right),~~y=\frac{\eta+\xi}{2}
\end{align}
Now we substitute the expressions of $u_{xx},u_{yy}$ in the PDE to get

\begin{align}
 4\mathrm{sech}^4\left(\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right)\right)&w_{\xi\eta}-2\tanh\left(\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right)\right)\nonumber\\&\mathrm{sech}^2\left(\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right)\right)(w_{\xi}-w_{\eta})=0
\end{align}
Which is
\begin{align}
    4\left(1-\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 w_{\xi\eta}-(\eta-\xi)\left(1-\left(\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\right)^2\right)(w_{\xi}-w_{\eta})=0 \nonumber
\end{align}
Which is the canonical form of the given PDE, for the domain $$\left\{\frac{\eta-\xi}{2}\in \mathbb{R}: -1< \frac{\eta-\xi}{2}<1 \right\}~~\blacksquare$$ Does this procedure seems correct? Thanks for any suggestions and help.